# Why DIR wont get the dir path? its just print it as it

Tags: php, windows, apache, security, .htaccess

the problem is when i use __ DIR __ in my php script, it prints `__DIR__` exactly.
so what is the cause of this problem?
and how can i solve it?
or at least is there any alternative way to do that? i mean getting the real directory on the web server.
assuming that the server running on windows OS, if that could helps anyway.

thank you

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? As `__DIR__` was recently added in PHP 5.3.0:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `__DIR__`

Comment: is there any possibility that it could returns a virtual path? i'm not sure if it possible to happen. but i still can't move the uploaded file to the given dir

Comment: move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"] , dirname(__ FILE __). "\\".$filename );

Comment: nop .. i don't get anything .. maybe better let the admin contact the hosting site and find out what is the problem again...i appreciate your help